# Execution order of dsp:input tags in ATG

Tags: forms, input, signal-processing, atg

While a form submit, I know that submit handler method (<"dsp:input" type="submit ..") processed finally after processing of all other type of "dsp:input" tags.

But, if we consider this other types of input tags only (not submit type), is there any specific order that they will get processed?

Is it the order that we define inside the JSP code?

Thanks,
Buddhika

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the documentation itself,

"DAF sets all properties from form input tags in a predetermined order. The ATG platform uses its own algorithm to determine the default order for processing form tags."

So it's not always the order of the tags within the jsp.  If you need a specific processing order, you can add the `priority` attribute to the input tag.

See docs on the [order of tag processing](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E52191_02/Platform.11-1/ATGPageDevGuide/html/s0706orderoftagprocessing01.html), and [dsp:input](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E52191_02/Platform.11-1/ATGPageDevGuide/html/s1318dspinput01.html)

Comment: When using the `priority` attribute! you have to bounce the server. It doesn't auto-reload like other changes to a .jsp.